# angularjs ui-router: find level of current state

Tags: regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

So I'm using ui-router and stateparams to nest child states, and it works well. I'm now trying to find a way to dictate a css class what state level the app is at. `main.route1.section1` would be 3 levels.

Here's some non-working code to help show:

```
<div ng-class="{findState().currentCount}"></div>

app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  $rootScope.findState = function() {
    var currentName = $state.current.name;
    var currentMatch = currentName.match(/./g);
    $rootScope.currentCount = currentMatch.length;
  };
});
```

I'm basically looking for a way to take `$state.current.name` which say equals `main.route1.section1` and split it at the dot and count how many are in the array and return that number to the mg-class. Unless you have a better idea... like a regex filter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look of the object `$state.$current` (instead of `$state.current`). In particular, the property `path` : it's an array representing the state hierarchy of the current state.

So what you are looking for is : `$state.$current.path.length`